# bitbucket stripped git revisions

Tags: git, bitbucket

After pushing to bitbucket my collegues commits are deleted and a message appears on bitbucket newsfeed

```
stripped 6f9de58aa748 from projektA
4 hours ago
stripped 54dae89de600 from projektA
4 hours ago
stripped e04022989a9d from projektA
...
```

How can I rescue the commits? 
Is Git really a versioning system that allows to delete commits?
Is this due to --force ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How can I rescue the commits?

Unfortunately there is nothing you can do on your site to get these commits back ([details](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Fetch-by-SHA-missing-td5604552.html)). You need to contact the BB service team since only they can restore these commits.

> Is Git really a versioning system that allows to delete commits?

When you configure it so. You have to set `receive.denyNonFastForwards` to `true` to disable this behavior in the repository on the server (which is the default when `git init` was run with the `--shared` option, but is false otherwise).

> Is this due to --force ?

Yes, using the force parameter on `git push` does make the server side git to disable the safety check if your new branch head throws away other commits, and `receive.denyNonFastForwards` is false.

Comment: Since Git is a distributed system, can the OP not retrieve the lost commits from his colleagues' local repos? At least, until they reset their local repos to match origin?

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else finds this thread searching frantically for "bitbucket stripped commits" as I was:

I managed to restore mine locally by following [these instructions](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html).

I then pushed to bitbucket again and the stripped commits were restored.

Comment: The reflog is indeed a great tool to undo local mistakes, but won't help if the commits you've overwritten were never on your local repo, such as when you force push to a remote which has newer commits than you do.

Answer (score 0):

We also faced this recently. Quite annoying, I must say. But in our case, the stripped commits were restored immediately after the original user pushed again. The other thing that we did to avoid this from happening again was to disable "History Re-writes" on the branch in question.

Hope this helps someone who faces this in future!