# GIT help! remote and local files are deleted

Tags: git

I am working on git and I forgot to `git fetch` before pushing. What happened is all files are deleted including my local files. On the logs says they are stripped. I tried reverting but nothing happens. Can anyone help me?

**Edit:** BTW, our git host is bitbucket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are pushing to a git hosting site (GitHub, BitBucket), you would need to contact that site to restore those stripped commits.
[As I mentioned before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770490/6309), reflogs aren't accessible from those upstream repositories.

See for instance "[bitbucket stripped git revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481346/bitbucket-stripped-git-revisions)".

If you have access to the upstream repo, then reflogs can help you, as in "[restoring lost commits](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/01/17/restoring-lost-commits.html)".

Comment: I tried checking out the your references and found out we have the same problem. So, I'll have contact bitbucket. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
git reflog
```

to see the history of where your git branches were pointing to. If you see something that happened before you did this push, simply use

```
git checkout <sha1>
```

to checkout to the state you had before.